# Bukkit spherical coordinates issue

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

This code uses the bukkit api for minecraft. However, this issue does not require bukkit knowledge or experience. The "particles" that I reference are spawned in using x, y, and z values that are part of a "Location" (bukkit class). The location can be thought of us as simply a coordinate in 3d space.
player.getDirection() is the unit vector of where a player is looking. I realize that this could be accomplished using the parametric equation for a circle in 3d. However, I would like to be able to move other objects in 3d. NOTE: In Minecraft, the y axis is what is commonly referred to as the z axis in math. (The y axis is straight up)

What its suppose to do:
The particle effect should act like a laser but instead of sending a line of particles, it should send a circle of particles that is perpendicular to player.getDirection(). After hours and hours of math theory, I was able to determine that to do this, I needed to create a circle about the x axis. Then, I needed to convert the coordinates from traditional cortesian coordinates to polar coordinates. This was needed so that I could move all of the points in the circle to generate the circle perpendicular to the player direction. Then, it would go off in that direction like a lazer.

What it is doing.
The particle effect works perfectly while the player direction vector lies along the xz plane. Inside of this plane, it shoots out the circle perpendicular to the player's direction. However, as the player increases or decreases the y component of his or her direction, the circle begins to get distorted. If a player creates the effect looking straight down, it generates a perfect figure 8. Looking straight up, the method does nothing. This is most likely due to the restriction of the domain on one of the trigonometric functions and should be easily solveable at the end. If a player looks almost straight up, it also generates a figure 8. In between parallel to the xz plane and the y axis, the shape is somewhere between a figure 8 and a circle.
There is no stack trace.
Here is my code for the method and a few internal classes that store data:

```
public void lazerBeamCircle(Player _player, String _particleType, double interval) 
    {
        MyLogger.info("In lazerBeamCircle in Particles");
        Vector playerDirection = _player.getLocation().getDirection();
        final int increment = 16;
        final double radius = 1;
        if (LazerCircleTaskID.get(_player.getName()) == null)
        {
            LazerCircleTaskID.put(_player.getName(), 0);
        }
        else if ((LazerCircleTaskID.get(_player.getName()) != 0))
        {
            Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask((LazerCircleTaskID.get(_player.getName())));
        }
         MyLogger.info("Right before the task");
        LazerCircleTaskID.put(_player.getName(), Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(JavaPlugin.getProvidingPlugin(MinigameDriver.class), new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {  
                    //MyLogger.info("In the task after run");
                    taskLazerBeamCircle _lazerVarsCircle = new taskLazerBeamCircle();
                    _lazerVarsCircle.Loc = new Location[increment];
                    if (!PlayerLazerCircleBeam.containsKey(LazerCircleTaskID.get(_player.getName())))
                    {
                        //double changeTheta = Math.acos(playerDirection.getX() / (Math.sin(Math.acos((playerDirection.getY())))));
                        double changeTheta = Math.atan2(playerDirection.getZ(), playerDirection.getX());
                        //if (changeTheta < 0 )
                        //{
                        //  changeTheta += 2 * Math.PI;
                        /*if (playerDirection.getZ() < 0)
                        {
                            changeTheta = ( 2 * Math.PI) - changeTheta;
                        }*/
                        double changePhi = (Math.acos(playerDirection.getY()) - (Math.PI)/2);

                        double ro;
                        double theta;
                        double phi;
                        double thetaNew;
                        double phiNew;

                        for (int i = 1 ; i <= increment; i++)
                        {
                            MyLogger.info("In the for calculating coords i = " + i);
                            MyLogger.info("inverse sin test " + Math.asin(Math.sqrt(2) / 2));
                            Location locThrowAway = new Location(_player.getWorld(), 1, 0, 0);
                            //finding the coords of the circle on the x axis;
                            locThrowAway.setY(radius * Math.sin(((double) i / increment) * (2 * Math.PI)));
                            locThrowAway.setZ(radius * Math.cos(((double) i / increment) * (2 * Math.PI)));
                            MyLogger.info("after Finding the coords of the circle on the x axis" + locThrowAway.getX() + "  " + locThrowAway.getY() + "  " + locThrowAway.getZ());

                            //finding the coords in spherical coords
                            ro = Math.sqrt((locThrowAway.getX() * locThrowAway.getX()) +
                                    (locThrowAway.getY() * locThrowAway.getY()) +(locThrowAway.getZ() * locThrowAway.getZ()));

                            phi = Math.acos((locThrowAway.getY()) / ro);
                            theta = Math.asin(locThrowAway.getZ() / (ro * Math.sin(phi)));
                            if (theta < 0)
                            {
                                theta += 2 * Math.PI;
                            }

                            //adding the arcs to the spherical coords
                            thetaNew = (theta + changeTheta);
                            phiNew = (phi + changePhi);
                            //thetaNew = theta;
                            //phiNew = phi;
                            /*if (phiNew < 0)
                            {
                                phiNew = phiNew * -1;
                            }*/


                            //converting back to normal coords
                            //changeTheta is used as it is theta as well
                            locThrowAway.setX(Math.sin(phiNew) * Math.cos(thetaNew) * ro);
                            locThrowAway.setY(Math.cos(phiNew) * ro);
                            locThrowAway.setZ(Math.sin(phiNew) * Math.sin(thetaNew) * ro);
                            //locThrowAway.setX(locThrowAway.getX());
                            //locThrowAway.setY(locThrowAway.getY());
                            //locThrowAway.setZ(locThrowAway.getZ());
                            locThrowAway.setX(locThrowAway.getX() + _player.getLocation().getX());
                            locThrowAway.setY(locThrowAway.getY() + _player.getLocation().getY() + 2);
                            locThrowAway.setZ(locThrowAway.getZ() + _player.getLocation().getZ());
                            _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i - 1] = locThrowAway;
                            //MyLogger.info("after converting back to normal coords" + locThrowAway.getX() + "  " + locThrowAway.getY() + "  " + locThrowAway.getZ());*/
                            /*Location center = _player.getLocation();
                            center.setX(center.getX() + center.getDirection().getX());
                            center.setY(center.getY() + center.getDirection().getY());
                            center.setZ(center.getZ() + center.getDirection().getZ());
                            double yaw = _player.getLocation().getYaw();
                            double pitch = _player.getLocation().getPitch();
                            yaw = Math.toRadians(yaw);
                            pitch = Math.toRadians(pitch);
                            Vector right = new Vector(Math.cos(yaw + (Math.PI/2.0)), 0, Math.sin(yaw + (Math.PI/2.0)));
                            Vector up = new Vector(Math.cos(yaw), Math.sin(pitch), Math.sin(yaw));
                            double a = 0;
                            Location[] DavidLocArray = new Location[16];
                            for (int j = 0; j < increment; j++) 
                            {
                                Location locThrowAway = new Location(_player.getWorld(), 1, 0, 0);
                                a = ((double) j / (double) increment) * (2 * Math.PI);
                                //MyLogger.info("a " + a);
                                locThrowAway.setX(center.getX() + (radius * Math.cos(a) * right.getX()) + (radius * Math.sin(a) * up.getX()));
                                locThrowAway.setY(center.getY() + (radius * Math.cos(a) * right.getY()) + (radius * Math.sin(a) * up.getY()));
                                locThrowAway.setZ(center.getZ() + (radius * Math.cos(a) * right.getZ()) + (radius * Math.sin(a) * up.getZ()));
                                //MyLogger.info("x,y,z " + locThrowAway.getX() + locThrowAway.getY() + locThrowAway.getZ());
                                int abc = _lazerVarsCircle.Loc.length;
                                //MyLogger.info("j = " + j);
                                Location throwAwayCopy = locThrowAway;
                                _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[j] = throwAwayCopy;
                                DavidLocArray[j] = locThrowAway;
                                //MyLogger.info("_lazerVarsCircle " + _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[j]);
                            }
                            //MyLogger.info("_lazerVarsCircle " + _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[14]);
                            for(int david = 0; david < increment; david++)
                            {
                                //MyLogger.info("_lazerVarsCircle[david] = " + DavidLocArray[david]);
                            }
                            */
                            //MyLogger.info("X , Y , Z after calculations " + locThrowAway.getX() + "  " + locThrowAway.getY() + "  " + locThrowAway.getZ());
                        }
                            PlayerLazerCircleBeam.put(LazerCircleTaskID.get(_player.getName()), _lazerVarsCircle);
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        _lazerVarsCircle = PlayerLazerCircleBeam.get(LazerCircleTaskID.get(_player.getName()));
                        /*for (int i = 0; i < _lazerVarsCircle.Loc.length; i++)
                        {
                            _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i].setX(_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i].getX() + (playerDirection.getX() / interval));
                            _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i].setY(_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i].getY() + (playerDirection.getY() / interval));
                            _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i].setZ(_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i].getZ() + (playerDirection.getZ() / interval));
                            if (_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i].getBlock().getType() != Material.AIR)
                            {
                                _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i].getWorld().createExplosion(_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[i], 5);
                                Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask((LazerCircleTaskID.get(_player.getName())));
                            }
                        }
                        PlayerLazerCircleBeam.put(LazerCircleTaskID.get(_player.getName()), _lazerVarsCircle);*/
                    }
                    for (int h = 0; h < increment; h++)
                    {
                    //  MyLogger.info("sending packets to display particles");
                    //  MyLogger.info("X , Y , Z particle locations " + _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[j].getX() + _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[j].getY() + _lazerVarsCircle.Loc[j].getZ());
                    //  MyLogger.info("index-1 " + h);
                        //MyLogger.info("Index " + h + "x coord" +_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[h].getX());
                        PacketPlayOutWorldParticles _packet = new PacketPlayOutWorldParticles(EnumParticle.valueOf(_particleType), true,
                                (float) (_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[h].getX()), (float) (_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[h].getY()), (float) (_lazerVarsCircle.Loc[h].getZ()),(float) 0,(float) 0,(float) 0,(float) 0, 1);
                            for(Player _online : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) 
                            {
                                ((CraftPlayer)_online).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(_packet);
                            }
                    }
                  //  MyLogger.info("about to exit run");
                }
            },0L, 2L));

    }                   
// Class used to store local values for the helix particle effect (SEE createHelix for more info)
class taskPlayerVariablesHelix
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
    boolean ParticleDirection;
    double NegativeY;
    Location Loc;
}
class taskLazerBeam
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
    Location Loc;
}
class taskLazerBeamCircle
{
    //array of locations used to store the locations of the points of the circle
    Location[] Loc;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.
Edit:
Here is a video of whats happening thanks to pokechu22
https://youtu.be/hU1uwZ9hiAI

Comment: Could we see your `LazerCircleTaskID` and `PlayerLazerCircleBeam` class?

Comment: @AdrianSohn `LazerCircleTaskID` seems to be a `Map<String, Long>` and `PlayerLazerCircleBeam` seems to be a `Map<Long, taskLazerBeamCircle>` based on the called methods, the OP should confirm.

Comment: Ah true, thanks, that makes more sense!

Comment: You are correct except they store an int. Thats just to cancel the repeating scheduled task later.

Comment: Don't overuse Math.atan2 too often. try to compute once and buffer the results. I've seen enough mods bogging down servers because they keypt recalculating with Math.atan2 over and over and over. it's a quite expensive function if called too often.

Comment: I only use it once...

Comment: This is a pretty well-written question, nicely done (addresses most of the possible questions).  But when you say "but instead of sending a line of particles, it should send a circle of particles that is perpendicular to player.getDirection()", do you mean basically a cone where the center line of the cone is player.getDirection()?

Comment: Actually, on re-reading, are you trying to create a [cylinder](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cylinder) or a [cone](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cone)?  (I haven't had a chance to actually try your code out and see how it works as-is)

Comment: It is a cylinder basically. Here is a link to my post on the bukkit forums that includes pictures. (Those guys are great but I think the math might be a bit much for that forum). https://bukkit.org/threads/advanced-particle-algorithm.402261/#post-3311412

Comment: Here's a video of the bug: https://youtu.be/hU1uwZ9hiAI (feel free to [edit] this into the question).  It makes it a lot easier to understand what's going on.  (I'm still looking into a fix)

Comment: Thats helpful @pokechu22 for people to see whats happening. Thanks!

Comment: From looking at the movie,it seems you first compensate for the player yaw, and then render the circle with the changed yaw component, but you should render the full circle first, en then offset every cordinate point with the change. But if I look at the code its confuses me whats exactly going on.

Comment: I first get the angle differences in ro and phi from where the player is looking to the center of the circle that I am drawing which is on the x axis. The first time I render the circle, the player's pitch and yaw do not come into factor.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to accomplish this would be using Linear Algebra to take in a 2D object (technically 3D object on a plane) and rotate it accordingly.
[image: Rotations in R3]
[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations ]

Your circle could have coordinates (x,y,0) and then you would transcribe it accordingly with the rotation matrices using [Matrix-vector multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Square_matrix_and_column_vector) where the vector is a coordinate of the object (x,y,0) and the matrix is the rotation matrix. Note: Another rotation matrix can then rotate the resulting vector from the first rotation matrix. The amount to rotate (theta) would be derived from the player's yaw and pitch.